# Unable to open Jupyter notebook in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook

I have created a free ubuntu instances on AWS ec2. I have installed jupyter notebook using command `pip install jupyter`. Please refer the screen shot showing [image: here]

But while I'm trying to run `jupyter notebook` or `jupyter notebook --generate-config`, I'm getting error message as `Command 'jupyter' not found`. Can you please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I use Jupyter too but I installed it completely different. You can install Anaconda3 which is used for python very often. From there, you can open the Anaconda3 prompt and use the simple command `jupyter notebook` to open it.